# Cannot use summary.nls

Tags: r

I have a nonlinear model and tried calling `summary.nls` but I get this error:

> Error: could not find function "summary.nls"

This is strange because I have the stats package installed and when I use `library(help="stats")` I see `summary.nls` listed. I can use other functions from the `stats` package such as `summary.lm` or `summary.aov` but for some reason `summary.nls` is not working.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You can use `summary.nls` with the following sintax: `stats:::summary.nls(nlsFit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `summary.nls()` directly. If you call `summary()` on an `nls` object, you'll get the behavior you want. From the help page

```
DNase1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1)
fm1DNase1 <- nls(density ~ SSlogis(log(conc), Asym, xmid, scal), DNase1)
class(fm1DNase1)
# [1] "nls"
summary(fm1DNase1)
```

These generic function implementations are often hidden (not exported directly from the package, even though they may be documented). If you run `methods(summary)` you'll get

```
 [1] summary.aov                    summary.aovlist*              
 [3] summary.aspell*                summary.check_packages_in_dir*
 [5] summary.connection             summary.data.frame            
 [7] summary.Date                   summary.default               
 [9] summary.ecdf*                  summary.factor                
[11] summary.glm                    summary.infl*                 
[13] summary.lm                     summary.loess*                
[15] summary.manova                 summary.matrix                
[17] summary.mlm*                   summary.nls*                  
[19] summary.packageStatus*         summary.PDF_Dictionary*       
[21] summary.PDF_Stream*            summary.POSIXct               
[23] summary.POSIXlt                summary.ppr*                  
[25] summary.prcomp*                summary.princomp*             
[27] summary.proc_time              summary.srcfile               
[29] summary.srcref                 summary.stepfun               
[31] summary.stl*                   summary.table                 
[33] summary.tukeysmooth*
```

The asterisk means the function is hidden. For generic functions like `summary()`, the proper version is called based on the `class()` of the first object passed to the function.